# Having trouble with jQuery and the hover event

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

What I want to do is when I hover over an image, I want the image to darken, and I want text to appear in the center of the darkened image. Please take a look at my code for a very rough example of what I want to happen.

What I have so far:
-- I am using the opacity property with jQ to darken the image on hover
-- I have the text centered using a css snippet I found a few months back that appears on hover using the display property

Basically I have all the components and it works ok until the cursor hovers over the text. As demonstrated in my fiddle, the opacity switches back and forth multiple times and does not stop until the mouse leaves the text.

tl;dr : How do I keep the text and opacity from switching back and forth when I hover over the text?

[Here is an example of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/darthkp/8ewmrvkx/5/)

CSS

```
.centered {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#news {
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    padding:20px 0px;
    background-color:#232323;
}
.newsImage {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
.newsImageOverlay {
    position:absolute;  
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background:none;
    z-index:3;
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(
    $("#a1").hover(
        function(){$("#a1").animate({opacity:'0.3'})},
        function(){$("#a1").animate({opacity:'1'});}
    );  
    $("#a1").hover(
        function(){$("#a1Ov").css("display","inline"), "slow"},
        function(){$("#a1Ov").css("display","none"), "slow";}
    );  
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="news" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="a1Ov" class="newsImageOverlay centered">Title 1</div>
        <img id="a1" src="project3.png" class="newsImage"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how my code could be more efficient/cleaner are welcome!

Comment: Practically _exactly_ the same question has been asked about 40 minutes ago. Let's see where it is...

Comment: Lol I didn't know how to search for what I needed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. What I ended up doing is overlaying the whole thing with a wrapper div, set it as the event selector, and made it invisible. If you had the same issue that I did, message me and I'll show you the method that I used

Answer (score 1):

Just add the hover effect to the text as well:

```
$("#a1, #a1Ov").hover(...
```

Comment: Edit: It did keep it from having the "blinking" effect but it still goes from full opacity to 0.2 opacity when the text is moused over. Definitely an improvement though

Answer (score 0):

add those lines to your css file:

```
-webkit-transform:(0);
-moz-transform:(0);
-o-transform:(0);
transform:(0);
```

it's should prevent it from blinking

Comment: And what about `ms-transform` and `khtml-transform`? I mean once we are on it we should _really_ pollute that file.

Comment: @arkascha I think its unnecessary

Comment: Yep, it is. But then again: three of four of the tags you posted are unnecessary.